# Looping through a list. End of file loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("test.txt", 'r')
fw = open("testouput.txt",'w')

for line in f:
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    while data != '':
        if data[0] == 'rectangle':
            r = Rectangle(float(data[1]), float(data[2]))
        elif data[0] == 'isoceles triangle':
            i = IsocelesTriangle(float(data[1]), float(data[2]))

    fw.write('rectangle, '+ str(r.get_perimeter()) + ',' + str(r.get_area()))                                    #if the object is made
    fw.write('isoceles triangle, ' + str(i.get_perimeter()) + ',' + str(i.get_area()))
```

I am reading a list of names and numbers and I am splitting it and taking out the `\n` character. However with this set up my `while data !=''` makes my compiler freeze. And if I don't use the while loop it gets stuck with the first one and then tells me my `i` object has not been declared, obviously because the loop exits after the first iteration. Can someone point me to how to check if it's the end of the file or the last item of a list to be able to see if I'm done checking or another way to loop until the end of the file so I can print the text to my other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you're expecting the loop to run once, for the entire file, but it runs per line in the file. The logic inside the loop need only handle a single line, so you can't use the `fw.write()` code you have to try and write both a triangle and a rectangle, because there can't be both of them on one line.

And if you do what you ask and wait until the end of the file before you write the results, that will only work while the file has one triangle and one rectangle, total. If it ever gets more than that, you'd have thrown one away by the time you get to the end, and only have the last one.

So you need something shaped more like:

```
for line in f:                                                           
    data = line.strip().split(',')

    if data[0] == 'rectangle':
        r = Rectangle(...
        fw.write("rectangle...."

    elif data[0] == 'isoceles triangle':
        i = IsocelesTriangle(...
        fw.write("isoceles triangle.."

print("Finished")
```

That way, for every line in the file, if it is a rectangle you create a rectangle and write the details. If it is a triangle you create one and write the details. And this works when the file has a single line, or two lines, or ten lines.

(You generally don't need to check if you're on the last line of a file, the `for` loop will go over every line in the file and then stop when it gets to the end. If you need to know what the last line was, it leaves the loop variable at the last value it had).

Comment: Yeah I had a misconception that the loop would only go to the first line and exit out. I moved everything inside the loop. I wanted to do a end of file check like c++. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` already loops. Remove the `while` statement. And make sure you actually do something with the objects in `r` and `i` before the end of the loop, making sure they have anything before using them.

Comment: well if my test file will either have 1 rectangle, 1 triangle or a combination of the two. Since my test file right now starts with a rectangle, then it gives me an error about i not being defined. Isn't the loop ending since the first if is coming up as true?

Comment: No, it's ending because you've reached the end of the file.